# How can I clip the text color to the background underneath the background div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am looking to create an effect like this where the image spans over the whole width of the container and a white div takes up half of the space on the left. Then a title that has a white background when on top of the image div and that displays the image when on top of the white div.

How would I go about doing this in css ? I believe I need to use background-clip property but I can't get it to work the way I want to.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image: Text displaying background]

**EDIT : So far here is where I'm at :**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="white left">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem
          eveniet tempora, debitis minus similique modi sapiente repudiandae,
          soluta ratione facilis consectetur! Deserunt distinctio, earum neque
          rem nam in non sed? Eaque dignissimos non beatae consequatur molestias
          voluptatum quia iusto illum exercitationem repellat facere cupiditate
          dolorum aspernatur, esse aut. Sapiente dolorum a aspernatur earum
          quidem voluptatem quaerat quod facilis perspiciatis beatae?
          Repudiandae tempore consequatur molestiae omnis a, deserunt quo
          aperiam amet eveniet. Dolores, eligendi quisquam sed dolor aspernatur
          minus? Aut amet delectus tempore harum eaque. Id itaque distinctio
          labore pariatur fuga! Incidunt, quasi cum! Incidunt exercitationem
          nobis porro alias at officia ad commodi, inventore iusto, laborum
          consequatur veniam aliquam voluptatibus tempore sit debitis. Quia, ut
          quae quaerat nesciunt soluta sequi ratione!
        </p>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">NOTRE DOMAINE</h1>
    </div>
```

Here is the styling for the container :

```
.container {
  background: center / cover url("assets/IMG_1138.jpg");
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  .white {
    width: 50vw;
    max-width: 50vw;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    p {
      padding: 170px 50px;
    }
  }
}
```

I managed to get the right separation between the left side of the text that has a background of image and the right side of the text that has a white background through a linear gradient like so :

```
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
    background-clip: text;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to left,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
      ),
      url("assets/IMG_1138.jpg");
    background-position: top left;
    background-size: 100% 100%, cover;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
```

The problem I am now facing is that the background position of the image on the left part of the text is not properly size to fit with the background image of the container...